# SharePoint 2013 custom web part not visible

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, custom-component, sitecollection

I'm trying to add a custom web part to a site collection in SharePoint 2013 (using VS2013). I deployed the web part with Visual Studio. The web part is actived and visible in SharePoint, except on the Site Collection page. I don't have a "custom" tab either.

Comment: can you post the contents of your .webpart file and the elements.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a problem sometime when deploying from VS to SP.
To resolve the deployment issues follow these steps:

1. Retract your solution from SP: open VS then Retract
2. Delete Your custom WebPart from WebPart Gallery: Go Site Collection
   Settings >> Web Parts
3. Deploy Your solution: go VS >> Deploy.
4. To be sure that you web part add correctly to SP: go Site Collection
   Settings >> Web Parts >> Files >> New Document >> select your custom
   WebPart and select Overwrite >> Then Populate gallery

Note: if You want to put your custom WebPart in a custom group, you must edit an attribute in WebPart Element file: go VS >> element.xml (under your WebPart ) >> then edit it like the below:

`<Property Name="Group" Value="Name of your custom Group" />`